Как создать блоки ввода формул на PyQt6?
В Word есть возможность создания формул благодаря конструктору, я хочу повторить похожий интерфейс, но не могу понять как создать такие же ячейки-блоки для ввода данных:
Я хочу реализовать такие блоки на PyQt6, но не знаю как подступиться.
Приложение должно иметь возможность предоставлять разные блоки на подобие тех, что есть в Word. При этом чтобы можно было получить значение из таких блоков, например в таком виде: {(dx)/(dx)}

Вот ключ "ячейки-блоки для ввода данных" . Подумайте над этим

@AlexanderChernin не нашел ничего подходящего на просторах сети(

А надо не в сети, а в Qt. Ячейки-блоки это поля ввода, которые можно разместить и настроить под ваши нужды
